# Best practices to update variables in app from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm sorry that the messy title, I couldn't come up with a better one, so if someone has one that he thinks is better, please update.
To the heart of the problem.
I have a Firebase Realtime Database with information, I have the following class:

```
public class FirebaseUtil implements Constants {

    private static final String fbRoot = "foods",
            fbName = "name",
            fbImage = "image";

    private static FirebaseUtil instance;

    public static FirebaseUtil getInstance() {
        return instance == null ? new FirebaseUtil() : instance;
    }

    private FirebaseDatabase mFBDB;
    private int mItemCount = 10;
    private boolean mItemCountUpdateRecently = false;

    private FirebaseUtil() {
        instance = this;
        mFBDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    }

    public void getNumberOfItems() {
        mFBDB.getReference(fbRoot).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new VEListenerWrapper(runnable) {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Inside of `getNumberOfItems()` I want to get the number of children of the branch called "foods" (`fbRoot`) and update it into `mItemCount`.
The way I approached it so far was to create a `ValueEventListener` wrapper, that has an interface, that will be executed once the `onDataChange` is done and update the value of me.
To be honest I think this is a really bad practice, and that is why I am trying to understand what is the best way to change a variable from inside the `ValueEventListener`, or what is the acceptable way to do it in general.
Please notice that I want to update a value **that doesn't exist in firebase.**

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update a value, you don't need to use a `ValueEventListener`, you just need to use `setValue()` method directly on the reference.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("name").setValue("John");
```

If you want to cont the number of childrens, then just use `getChildrenCount()` method directly on the `dataSnapshot` object. But remember, for setting this number to a view, use set method inside `onDataChange` method, because this method is called asynchronously.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, the question wasn't clear enough, correcting it.